# Найти номера и координаты точек, наиболее удалённых друг от друга

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

На вход подаётся N точек, заданных парой координат x и y. Найти номера и координаты точек, наиболее удалённых друг от друга. Расстояние между точками определять с помощью функции. (2 балла вы получаете за полное соблюдение формата вывода)
У меня была вот такая идея для кода, но дальше немного не понимаю, что сделать, то ли сравнивать каждый элемент массива, то ли что

```
import math
def f(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    return math.sqrt(((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2))
mas_x = []
mas_y = []
numbers = int(input())
for i in range(numbers):
    x,y = map(int,input().split())
    mas_x.append(x)
    mas_y.append(y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В паре вложенных циклов обходите все пары точек.

```
for i in range(numbers):
   for j in range(i+1, numbers):
       dist = f(mas_x[i],mas_y[i],mas_x[j],mas_x[j])
```

Для более оптимального решения  (я думаю, в вашем случае этого не требуется)- строите выпуклую оболочку (convex hull), проходите по ней с помощью rotating calipers.

Comment: честно у меня нету идей, что делать дальше. Сравнивать отдельные элементы массива x[j] с x[i]?

Comment: добавил вычисление расстояния с вашей функцией. Осталось максимум обновлять

Comment: @Rendivy вычисляете расстояние для данной пары точек `dist = f(mass_x[i],mass_y[i], mass_x[j],mass_y[j])`, Как вариант, сохраняете его вместе с координатами ещё в один список `mass_dist.apend((dist, mass_x[i],mass_y[i], mass_x[j],mass_y[j])`, дальше просто сортируете этот список. Или ручками хранить максимум и обновлять.